# IBM Worklight - How to style the Busy Indicator

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I am trying to figure out how to change the background styling of the `BusyIndicator`. See below code snippet and explanation:

```
app.busyIndicator = new WL.BusyIndicator('content', { text: message, bounceAnimation: false, fullScreen: true, minDuration: 3, textColor: "white", opacity: 1, strokeOpacity: 0.25 });
```

This snippet will force the busy indicator to take up the entire window of a iPhone mobile device when invoked. This behaviour is different on Android devices.

Here are my questions:

1. Inside a device, how do I change the background color from flat black to another color or transparent?
2. I have overriden the CSS classes related to the `BusyIndicator` layout...which does work when tested in a browser. However, I still only see the black background when the app has been pushed to a device. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to change the background color of the Busy Indicator.

- For iOS 6 it is black
- For iOS 7 it appears lighter and more transparent

The above is relevant starting Worklight v6.0.0.1, released some days ago.

- If you are an IBM customer or Business Partner, and you are using an older version of Worklight, contact IBM via your contact person to get this update.

---

1. Android and iOS have different options for their respective Busy Indicator. Not all options apply to both OSs, obviously. Othen than the provided options, it is not customizable.
2. When used in a mobile device the Busy Indicator is a native component, thus CSS does not apply to it.
3. The Web/Air/Desktop/BB6/7/10/Preview environments use a HTML/CSS/JS-based Busy Indicator, which is why you are able to change its looks via CSS.

This is explained in the [Common UI Controls](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/05_02_Common_UI_Controls.pdf) training module starting page 6. Please read. [More training modules](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html).

Comment: Idan, I appreciate the feedback. I did read the UI modules which pointed me to attempt changes in CSS. I do realize that the busyindicator is invoked as native...which is why the question I asked. We are testing in iOS6 and iOS7 using Worklight 6 and the color is the same. At current, the loading spinner looks ok with black but I am trying to get away with ONLY using the busyindicator in Worklight and not creating a custom spinner in iOS and Android. There must be something on Worklight (like the Cordova plugin) that can be customized.

Comment: Then you did not read my answer. As I wrote - in Worklight 6.0.0.0 there is only black busy indicator. Also, Worklight 6.0.0.0 does NOT support iOS 7 (you will be facing issues, crashing, weird status bar, etc... To resolve this, you need to upgrade to Worklight 6.0.0.1. In 6.0.0.1 there is a different color for the busy indicator when used in iOS 7; still, you cannot customize this color. The native busy idicator in iOS is a component creatd by Worklight and it is not customizable in this aspect (unfortunatly).

Comment: Idan, I am understanding you and did read your answer. Again, I appreciate the information. My objective is to obtain a busy indicator that is not custom within a device (iOS and Android). If worklight cannot be customized as of yet, then I guess my only choice is to make a native component. Worklight should be more flexible to allow customized interfaces regardless of platform and should be easily accessible and documented within the API instructions.

Comment: Worklight creates what is expected to be displayed in the specific environment, hence why it is called a native component. You can use either Cordova (not sure about them in this respect, actually) or a 3rd party framework like jQuery Mobile to achieve a custom busy indicator that looks the same across platforms (there's a training module about 3rd party frameworks).

Comment: Awesome...appreciate the help, Idan.